# How to list files from Google Drive shared folder and make a download

Tags: java, android, rest, google-drive-api

Im trying to list a Google drive shared folder and make a download of a file, i statred from the G-Drive JAVA Sample of this url: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

The code is :

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
    }
```

is it possible to do sush action without autorisations problem ?

Comment: What do you mean authorization problem? Proper authorization can make it possible to list files from shared folder and be able to download it. Also with proper scopes to be use you should not encounter any issues.

Comment: Is there a method to define the folderId like this : service.files(folderID).list() so i can read a shared folder ?

Comment: Yup, you can define it in the query parameter and adding value to the statement: `"'1234567' in parents"`. Look at the  sample code in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters#using_client_libraries)